# Circuitmaker Dragging a component with its track

Tags: pcb, altium, circuitmaker

I draw my PCB and now I would like to make fine tuning on the PCB. Therefore, I'd like to shift some components. However, there is no property under the **System Preferences -> PCB Editor -> Interactive Routing**

Altium has this option to shift the part with the track but I couldn't find it in Circuit maker. Please help me with it.

[image: Circuitmaker System Preferences Window]

Answer (score 0):

In Altium Designer 18.0 and up - check the setting under: PCB Editor, General, Other, Comp Drag. Selecting "Connected Tracks" should allow tracks to move with the component.  See the reference at Altium.com topic ["Connection lines & move component"](https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/connecting-lines-move-component). For Altium CircuitMaker see similar setting at: [CircuitMaker Preferences.](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-circuitmaker/system-preferences#!system-preferences)

Comment: This is not Altium. This is Altium’s free CAD software called circuitmaker.

Comment: It seems that some of the same preference are available in the CircuitMaker version, (see answer edits above)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked it but I think in the latest version, I don't have the option that the manual shows. :( I don't know what to do.